# Ant create process error cygwin

Tags: java, bash, ant, cygwin

I am trying to run a simple ant build that has one target that runs a bash shell script within cygwin.  When I run the build, the target seems to run but the executable does not.  Instead I get a Java IO Exception: Create Process error=193.  If I run the script standalone it works fine.  At the minute I am using a test.sh which only has one command, echo a message to the screen.

I understand that running scripts from cygwin is maybe not best practise, but integrating the scripts functions into the ant build is something I want to do after I get this short term solution working.

My XML is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="TestProject" default="exec_build_config" basedir=".">
<property name="test" location="test.sh"/>
<target name="exec_build_config" >
                <exec executable="${test}">
                </exec>
        </target>
</project>
```

My shell script...

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "testing !!!"
```

It just doesn't work :( Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the equivalent of:

```
sh test.sh
```

? (i.e. specify the executable as `sh` with an associated argument).

Doing the above will tell Ant to execute `sh` with the argument of your test shell script. I suspect the `#!` syntax won't be respected by the Java program spawner mechanism, since it's Unix-specific.

Comment: How about giving it the full path to the executable, something like c:/some/path/sh.exe test.sh?

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head I've discovered what was causing the issue.  It looks like an installation of QTP had changed some of my environment variables, after I reset these it seems to work just fine! Thanks anyway!